# Multi-Threading proxy checker Object not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm trying to make a multi-threaded proxy checker.

I already have a kinda working checker but it gives me this error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I don't know how to solve it and I also don't know why its giving me that error.

Can someone explain me why it is giving me this error and how I should handle it?

Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub checkProxys(ByVal location As Integer)
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    Dim proxy As String

    Do Until location >= ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

        Dim countitems = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        ' Console.WriteLine("Location: " & location & "|  Listbox Items: " & ListBox1.Items.Count.ToString & "|  Items - 1: " & countitems.ToString)

        Dim myProxy As WebProxy
        proxy = ListBox1.Items(location).ToString
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(location)

        Try
            myProxy = New WebProxy(proxy)
            Dim r As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com")
            r.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36"
            r.Timeout = TrackBar2.Value
            r.Proxy = myProxy
            Dim re As HttpWebResponse = r.GetResponse()
            ListBox2.Items.Add(proxy)
            Label9.Text = "Working proxy's: " & ListBox2.Items.Count.ToString
            Label4.Text = "Proxy's loaded: " & ListBox1.Items.Count
        Catch
            ListBox3.Items.Add(proxy)
            Label10.Text = "Unresponsive proxy's: " & ListBox3.Items.Count.ToString
            Label4.Text = "Proxy's loaded: " & ListBox1.Items.Count
        End Try
    Loop

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If ListBox1.Items.Count < 1 Then
        MsgBox("Make sure to import a proxy list first.")
    Else
        For x As Integer = 1 To TrackBar1.Value
            Dim checkProxyThread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf checkProxys)
            checkProxyThread.Start(x)
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

error occures at this line: ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(location)

Comment: Your are removing items from `ListBox1` inside the loop. This is probably  breaking your looping logic.

Comment: Why do you need to remove the items in the loop? Can you remove them after the loop?

Comment: Where is the `location` variable defined?

Comment: @YacoubMassad its defined at the first line

Comment: @YacoubMassad I need to check all proxys in de listbox but afcourse i dont want another thread to check the same proxy so i have to remove them from the listbox so it doesn't get checked by another thread

Comment: So you want each thread to handle one item in the ListBox? I am assuming this is a UI application? Only the UI thread can access the UI element such as the ListBox. So `checkProxys` shouldn't access UI elements since it runs on a non-UI thread.

Comment: By the way, which line throws the exception?

Comment: I edited my question with the line of exception. Also the loop focusses on 1 index of the listbox. since it deletes the index item when its done an new index item will come up at that place. also checkProxys is an thread wich access the listbox in a non-invoke way. but that is for testing purposes.

Comment: I suggest you do the following: 1) extract all input from UI, 2) use threads to create your web requests uses these data (that is no longer in the UI), 3) after the threads finish, update the UI from the UI thread. There are a lot of ways to do this. You might want to consider using async and await.

Comment: Thanks you gave me a good idea wich resulted in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you access a listbox with alot of threads its kinda unstable when deleting an index because every other item gets an new index wich is the old index - 1

I think this is kinda unstable so as Yacoub Massad mentioned in his comment its better to keep the data in there. And that's exactly what I did.

I found out that I dont need to delete the data. I simply need to go to another index wich isn't edited or used by any other thread. What did I do to solve the problem:

1. Delete the line: ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(location)
2. Just before the loops ends I wrote this line: location = location +
   TrackBar1.Value

TrackBar1.value is the thread count.

This way the threads are never at the same index or item.
This answer is based on what I think that caused the problem.